# How to unit test custom prompt that requires user select a choice in Bot Framework

Tags: c#, json, unit-testing, botframework, adaptive-cards

I have some custom prompts made with adaptive cards which require user inputs such as input.ChoiceSet and input.Text.

My problem here is if I have a card with 3 choices ('Red', 'Blue', 'Green'), and I would like to test the result of "Red" being selected. How do I send the choice and get result in my test code.
I would like to unit test the result and flow after something is selected and the user hit the submit button.

I use JObject to get the user's selection as a string;

In the constructor of my dialog class I have add the prompt to the dialog.

```cs
AddDialog(new CustomPrompt("cardPrompt", DialogValidators.AdaptiveCardValidatorAsync));
```

Here is my dialog code for testing.

```cs
private async Task<DialogTurnResult> aStep(WaterfallStepContext stepContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
            var adaptiveActivity = stepContext.Context.Activity.CreateReply();
            adaptiveActivity.AddCardAttachment();
            return await stepContext.PromptAsync(
                "CardPrompt",
                new PromptOptions
                {
                    Prompt = adaptiveActivity,
                    RetryPrompt = MessageFactory.Text("xxx"),
                    Validations = new List<string> { "selectionCard" }
                });
}

private async Task<DialogTurnResult> bStep(WaterfallStepContext stepContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
            JObject answerObject = (JObject)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(stepContext.Result.ToString());
            string userChoice = answerObject["choiceID"].ToString();
}
```

Below is my test code.

```cs
userState = new UserState(new MemoryStorage());
var subDialog = new SubDialog(userState);
var MainDialog = new MainDialog(subDialog);
var testClient = new DialogTestClient(Channels.Msteams, MainDialog);

// some code here

reply = await testClient.SendActivityAsync<IMessageActivity>("Red");
Assert.AreEqual(XXXX, reply....);
```

How to work with DialogTestClient for the test?

Appreciate your time for this.

**Update**

Below is my prompt class. It extends Prompt2 which has abstract methods (OnPromptAsync and OnRecognizeAsync) and extends Dialog class.

```cs
public class CustomPrompt : Prompt2<string>
    {
        public CustomPrompt(string dialogId, PromptValidator<string> validator = null)
            : base(dialogId, validator)
        {
        }

        protected async override Task OnPromptAsync(ITurnContext turnContext, IDictionary<string, object> state, PromptOptions options, bool isRetry, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
        {
            if (turnContext == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(turnContext));
            }

            if (options == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(options));
            }

            if (isRetry && options.RetryPrompt != null)
            {
                await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(options.RetryPrompt, cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
            }
            else if (options.Prompt != null)
            {
                await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(options.Prompt, cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
            }
        }

        protected override Task<PromptRecognizerResult<string>> OnRecognizeAsync(ITurnContext turnContext, IDictionary<string, object> state, PromptOptions options, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
        {
            if (turnContext == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(turnContext));
            }

            var result = new PromptRecognizerResult<string>();
            if (turnContext.Activity.Type == ActivityTypes.Message)
            {
                var message = turnContext.Activity.AsMessageActivity();
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(message.Text))
                {
                    result.Succeeded = true;
                    result.Value = message.Text;
                }

                /*Add handling for Value from adaptive card*/
                else if (message.Value != null)
                {
                    result.Succeeded = true;
                    result.Value = message.Value.ToString();
                }
            }

            return Task.FromResult(result);
        }
    }
```

Here is the structure of my card.

```
{
  "type": "AdaptiveCard",
  "body": [
    {
      "type": "Container",
      "items": [
        {
          "type": "Input.ChoiceSet",
          "wrap":  true,
          "id": "choiceID",
          "value": {defaultValue}
          "placeholder": "Placeholder text",
          "choices": [
            {
              title: "aaaa",
              value: "testChoice"
            }
          ],
          "style": "expanded"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "actions": [
    {
      "type": "Action.Submit",
      "id": "submit",
      "title": "Confirm",
      "data": {
        "value": "submit",
        "id": selectionCard"
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Action.Submit",
      "id": "cancel",
      "title": "Cancel",
      "data": {
        "value": "cancel",
        "id": "selectionCard"
      }
    }
  ],
  "$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
  "version": "1.1"
```

I was wondering how do I test if I select any choice of the card and get proper response from the bot using TestFlow.
Thanks.

Comment: Thank you for the question, and good job on the code so far. DialogTestClient has some limitations. Is it an option to use TestFlow instead?

Comment: Are you still working on this?

Comment: Yes, Thanks for the reply. I tried a bit with TestFlow. It seesms to be a good replacement of DialogTestClient, but I didn't find much documentation. Is there any sample code or guide because I have some issues in using TestFlow and Mock in my tests.

Comment: In order for us to know how to test your prompt, we need to know what your prompt is. It sounds like you've created an Adaptive Card prompt, so you already know how to interpret the value-based messages returned by submit actions. Can you show us the code from your custom prompt that does this?

Comment: Yes, I created an Adaptive card prompt. And I used JObject to handle the response. I updated some info above. But didn't know how to test the selection of the card using TestFlow.

Comment: The line of code you pasted is not what I asked for. It looks like you pasted code from a waterfall step that reads the result of your prompt, and you haven't actually shown us what your prompt does. We can see that you're reading `stepContext.Result`, but you haven't shown us how you've gotten the submit action data into `stepContext.Result` in the first place. This is important because the way you're reading the data in the prompt will inform how you should write the data in the test. Also, please correct your malformatted card so that it contains valid JSON.

Comment: Do you still need help?

Comment: Yes, thanks for the reply. In my dialog, I get the submit data by using answerObject[xxxx] where xxxx is the ID of the choiceSet.  So I was wondering if the promp is a choiceSet card that requires user select an option, how do I test it with testFlow. Appreciate.

Comment: Thanks for that information. Please do edit the relevant code into your question so we can see where `answerObject` comes from and how it relates to the incoming activity. Ideally, we would like to see the entire prompt class.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I updated some code above showing how I get user's choice from the card via answerObject and my prompt class.

Comment: Is my answer acceptable?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply after holidays. It worked, appreciate! Happy new year!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code in your prompt class reveals that Adaptive Card submit action data gets transferred to the bot in the activity's value property:

> ```cs
> /*Add handling for Value from adaptive card*/
> else if (message.Value != null)
> {
>     result.Succeeded = true;
>     result.Value = message.Value.ToString();
> }
> ```

All you must do in the test is to simulate sending such an activity by populating its value property yourself.

```cs
var activity = new Activity(ActivityTypes.Message, value: submitActionData);
reply = await testClient.SendActivityAsync<IMessageActivity>(activity);
```

This should work with either dialog test client or test flow. You can see some examples of this in my [cards library tests](https://github.com/BotBuilderCommunity/botbuilder-community-dotnet/blob/develop/tests/Bot.Builder.Community.Cards.Tests/Management/CardManagerMiddlewareTests.cs).