# Simulating Adaptive Card Inputs Using the Microsoft Bot Framework Testing Package

Tags: botframework

I have developed a chat bot using the Microsoft Bot Framework in Python that has a dialog with multiple steps. Each step prompts the user with an adaptive card for so that they can make a selection that will inform the next step.

I have tried using the Testing package in the Bot Framework, but I haven't been able to simulate sending an adaptive card input from one of these steps back to the bot so that I can test the dialog. I can send text inputs to the bot using the package fine to start the dialog.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/unit-test-bots?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp

Does anyone know if there is a way to simulate sending an adaptive card input using the Testing package in the Bot Framework?

At the moment the workaround to this seems to be that we need to deploy the bot to an application in Azure and then run the tests against that using something like the Direct Line API. It would be great if all of these tests could be run locally.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What have you tried so far? Can you show us your prompt code that handles the Adaptive Card submit actions? Please have a look at the handy guide to see the steps you can take to get a better answer faster: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: This is curiously similar to another question that was asked just a few days ago, though that was a C# bot and not Python. Do you have any connection to this other question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65151720/how-to-unit-test-custom-prompt-that-requires-user-select-a-choice-in-bot-framewo

Comment: Are you still working on this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to unit test custom prompt that requires user select a choice in Bot Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65151720/how-to-unit-test-custom-prompt-that-requires-user-select-a-choice-in-bot-framewo)